# is there priority in plugin and dependencies in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

When I setupr gradle file like this every thing is ok:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but when I swap the dependencies and plugin, I get this error:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
```

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 9.0.0, 11.0.4. Examples include
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0 and
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.4

Is there any priority in gradle structure and how this relates to the version? Is `com.google.gms.google-services` a general syntax for all versions and if not, How should I customize its version here?

Comment: Android Studio has an assistant to do this, is good to know what you do, but the purpouse of the assistant is to prevent human error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` should always be at the real bottom of your `build.gradle`

> The `google-services` plugin has two main functions:
>
> 1. Process the `google-services.json` file and produce Android resources that can be used in your application's code. See [Adding the JSON File](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file) more information.
> 2. Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled. This step requires that the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line be at the **bottom** of your `app/build.gradle` file so that no dependency collisions are introduced. You can see the result of this step by running `./gradlew :app:dependencies`.

[The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)